# C Compiler ignores scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have problem with this code:

```
printf("Select your math: \n'+'addition \n'-'subtraction \n'*'multiplication \n'/' division \n");
char do_math;
scanf("%c", &do_math);
printf("Type 1 st number: ");
```

Problem is, that program doesn't wait until I type "do_math" but it displays "Type 1 st number: " right after first printf. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to see what is happening to `do_math`?

Comment: Yeah, it just ignores it.

Comment: The compiler don't ignore `scanf`. You could look at the generated assembly code (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -O -S`). You'll find that `scanf` is still referenced there. You are just using `scanf` *wrongly*

Answer (score 3):

The only way your compiler will miscompile that is if you deliberately defined `scanf()` as a do-nothing macro.  Don't blame your compiler!

There is probably a previous `scanf()` call in the program that left a carriage return in the input buffer.  You can confirm that hypothesis by printing the value of `do_math`.

Try `scanf(" %c", &do_math);` (with a space before `%c`) to discard such whitespace.

(It's also a good idea to pay attention to the return value from `scanf()`.)

Comment: Instead of a "thank you" comment, could you please mark the answer as accepted?